# pagePath in Google Analytics Data API (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics-api

Is it no longer possible to get the 'pagePath' dimension via the Google Analytics Data API?

At least it's not in the dimension list: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/realtime-api-schema

Is there any alternative?